# Last added date not showing in table

Tags: mysql, sql

Why is it not showing my last added sales? In my table data, I have added a sales which the date of it is 2021-01-19 but after I execute my query, the data which has a date of 2021-01-19 is not showing. I tried this <= but I got the same result. When I change the second value '2021-01-19' to '2021-01-20' it displays the row with 2021-01-19.

My Table:
[image: table data]

My query:

```
SELECT tsd.sales_so, tsd.sales_dr, tsd.sales_si, tsd.sales_po, tsd.sales_date, tsd.sales_company, tsd.sales_particulars, tsd.sales_net_amount, SUM(tsp.payment_amount) AS amount_paid, tsp.payment_date, tsd.sales_balance, tsp.payment_remarks 
FROM tbl_sales_details AS tsd 
LEFT JOIN tbl_sales_payments AS tsp ON tsd.sales_id = tsp.sales_id 
WHERE (tsd.sales_date >= '2021-01-01' AND tsd.sales_date < '2021-01-19') 
GROUP BY tsd.sales_id
```

Result:
[image: table query]

Comment: It's an example. I'm using daterangepicker and pass the value to query. So far now, I'm just testing it.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing Date and Datetime fields the comparison uses Datetime type. This means that when you have a condition such as:

```
WHERE tsd.sales_date < '2021-01-19'
```

Your condition in reality becomes:

```
WHERE tsd.sales_date < '2021-01-19 00:00:00'
```

Obviously, every point in time on the 19th will be outside of your comparison range. If you want to include the whole day of 2021-01-19 too then you need to check the range is less than the next day. e.g.

```
WHERE tsd.sales_date < '2021-01-20'
```